# Calculate Distance Between Two Postcodes In PHP

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to calculate the distance between two postal codes in India. I've found the Google Map API and I'm trying to use it with this code:

```
$url =
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=144216&
destinations=160017&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false";
   $data   = @file_get_contents($url);
   $result = json_decode($data, true); //print_r($result);  //outputs the array    $distances = array( // converts the units
   "meters" => $result["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["value"],
   "kilometers" => $result["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["value"] / 1000,
   "yards" => $result["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["value"] * 1.0936133,
   "miles" => $result["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["value"] * 0.000621371    );        
print_r($distances);
```

It is showing this output:

```
Array ( 
  [meters] => 5497949 
  [kilometers] => 5497.949 
  [yards] => 6012630.1491217 
  [miles] => 3416.266068079
)
```

The resulting distance is much bigger than it should be. The actual distance between these places is about 200 km.

What can I do to make this work correctly?

Comment: No description, only code?

Comment: Its showing output Array ( [meters] => 5497949 [kilometers] => 5497.949 [yards] => 6012630.1491217 [miles] => 3416.266068079 ). which is not correct . Please let me know any solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the result from google you will notice that it is calculating a route from india to russia.

```
"destination_addresses" : [ "Wologda, Oblast Wologda, Russland, 160017" ],
"origin_addresses" : [ "Punjab 144216, Indien" ],
```

This happens because you only provided postal codes, without reference from which country they are. I assume you want to calculate a route within india, since your profile shows that you are from there.

If you just add `,india` to your postal codes, like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=144216,india&destinations=160017,india&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false
```

You get a result that looks much more like what you want:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Chandigarh, 160017, India" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Punjab 144216, India" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "201 km",
                  "value" : 200693
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 30 mins",
                  "value" : 12625
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```