# Finding closest location (selected from list) to a given address

Tags: database, list, location, street-address, closest

I need to find the closest location from a user's address to the list of other users' addresses which is selected from the database. How can I do that?

user's address:
Via dei Fori Imperiali
00186 Roma
Italia

list of addresses:
1)Via Alessandrina
00186 Roma
Italia

2)Via XXXXXXX
XXXXX Milano
Italia

RETURN 1, which is the closest address to user's address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a record of latitude & longitude equivalents for all the postcodes in the country(ies) you will be dealing with, you'll have to use the Google Maps API.

Have a look here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

Example URL and output here: [Calculate Distance Between Two Postcodes in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261707/calculate-distance-between-two-postcodes-in-php)